# When does a delegate setter get called in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

My code works, but I don't understand who or where is calling the setter for my view's datasource delegate. I understand why calling that code makes everything work, I'd just like to know who makes the call / where it happens. The header for the view looks like this, with the last line of code being the important one:

```
@class GraphView;

@protocol GraphViewDataSource 

-(float)YValueforXValue:(float)xValue;

@end

@interface GraphView : UIView

@property (nonatomic) CGFloat scale;
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint graphOrigin;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet id <GraphViewDataSource> dataSource;

@end
```

And the view controller that conforms to the protocol:

```
@interface GraphViewController () <GraphViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet GraphView *graphview;

@end

@implementation GraphViewController

@synthesize graphview = _graphview;
@synthesize program = _program;

-(void)setGraphview:(GraphView *)graphview {
    _graphview = graphview;
    self.graphview.dataSource = self;
}
```

I have excluded the required protocol method and more, as its not relevant. What I want to know is who calls the above `setGraphView` method. Unfortunately, I couldn't get help from a breakpoint (aside from knowing it was being called).

Also, that delegate first gets referenced by this code in the view:

```
for (CGFloat thisPointViewXValue=self.bounds.origin.x; thisPointViewXValue<=self.bounds.size.width; thisPointViewXValue +=1/self.contentScaleFactor)
    {
        if (FirstPoint) {
            CGFloat firstpointGraphXValue = [self convertViewXValueToGraphXValue:thisPointViewXValue];
            CGFloat firstpointGraphYValue = [self.dataSource YValueforXValue:firstpointGraphXValue];
            CGFloat firstpointViewYValue = [self convertGraphYValueToViewY:firstpointGraphYValue];
            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, thisPointViewXValue, firstpointViewYValue);
            FirstPoint = NO;

        }
        CGFloat thisPointGraphXValue = [self convertViewXValueToGraphXValue:thisPointViewXValue];
        CGFloat thisPointGraphYValue = [self.dataSource YValueforXValue:thisPointGraphXValue];
        CGFloat thisPointViewYValue = [self convertGraphYValueToViewY:thisPointGraphYValue];
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, thisPointViewXValue, thisPointViewYValue);


}
```

Is that where it happens???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graphView and dataSource iVars are marked as IBOutlets, i.e. Interface Builder Outlet.

This would normally indicate that GraphViewController is loaded via a nib/xib file, and inside that nib file there are connections to these iVar from other objects inside the nib file.

So it is the nib loading mechanism that is calling the setters on those iVars.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it was probably something under the hood, but I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything.

Comment: Have a read of the resource programming guide if you want to learn more about how it works. It's good to know: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW8

Answer (score 0):

there  self.graphview.dataSource = self;

Comment: no, that's not my question. I see that that line of code makes the connection, but who is calling that setter in the first place?